# azurewebsites.net was already mapped, but still apears

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I followed **exactly** the [description by Microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name-portal/) to map their web apps on one's own external domain. And the redirection is even correct.

But my purpose was to map mydaylivery.com to the mydayliveryop.azurewebsites.net, so that the mydayliveryop.azurewebsites.net **is replaced** by my mydaylivery.com domain. However, there is just a redirection, but no replacement.

In my azure portal under the web app dashboard and beside "URL" is also mydaylivery.com mentioned. But if you go on mydaylivery.com, you see that there is still the azurewebsites.net subdomain.

Comment: This type of question has been asked before, but... it belongs on ServerFault or SuperUser; it's not programming-related.

Comment: Okay, so it seems that I have to reask it there.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [dig web interface](https://www.digwebinterface.com/) to check your dns. It seems that you don't configure the domain correctly. The article you provide is suitable for Azure cloud service not Azure web App. I would suggest you have a look at [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/). Please note below part in the article:

*To use an A record to map to your Azure app's IP address, you actually need to create **both an A record and a TXT record**.*

Comment: Unfortunately this approach was not successful. I also followed this article, which is quite similar to the article I already read, and the A record and the TXT record were already created.